# countries do not receive apns?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

countries do not receive apns?
Apple Push push requests to the server in China
Normally push for me in Korea.
But in China, I'm a problem to those who do not push ..

Do not know what to test in any way ...
Known, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Any country which can reach `apple.com` can receive apns I guess, so your answer may be North Korea.